# Which edition of the ECMAScript standard is actually implemented in Chrome V8?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-harmony

Which edition of the ECMAScript standard is actually implemented in Chrome V8?

According to the introduction page to Chrome V8 on the Google Developers website, V8 implements the ECMA-262 5th edition specification (content last updated: September 17, 2012).

Yet on the front page of the Chrome V8 product on the Google Developer website it says that V8 implements the ECMA-262 3rd edition specification (content last updated June 17, 2014).

Aren't we already in the process of incorporating features from the ECMAScript 6th edition specification? I imagine we've fully implemented the 5th edition at this point.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 supports ES5 [in its entirety](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't disagree. Feel free to edit my answer or post your own.